# accessing user credentials/permissions

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Is there an easy way to get a credential/permission for a particular user?

I've seen the `hasCredential()` method, but I'd like to dynamically check any user, not just the current user.

I know I can use `sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();` to get the current user object, but is there a way to load in any user and get his/her credentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of depends on the "store" you're using. In Symfony the current user (the one provided with `sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()`) is more an abstraction of the session.

So the most used plugin for authentication, sfDoctrineGuard, has controllers (sfGuardAuth) which handle things like a a signin form, and once succesful, it will populate the `sfUser` accordingly.

So, if you want to check for the permissions of a user, you will have to check the underlying store. If you're using `sfDoctrineGuard`, you can retrieve a User model through `sfGuardUserTable::getInstance()->find(...)`. On the `sfGuardUser`, you can call the `hasPermission($name)` function to check.

Comment: My user setup is, I have a admin and a moderator. An admin has several moderators. What I'm looking to do, is check the credentials of the parent admin of the moderator I am logged in as. So ideally I need to get the crrent user (easy enough), but then get it's admin relation and get the admin's credentials

Comment: Something like: `$user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser(); $user->getProfile()->getAdmin()->getUser()->hasCredential('Can.Delete');` but obviously this doesn't work

Comment: Are you using sfDoctrineGuard? If so, you can use `$user->getUserModel()->getAdmin()->hasPermission('Can.Delete')`. You'll only need to define the `getAdmin()` function in the `sfGuardUser` model (if it's not a relation already).

Comment: Ok, so I have managed to figure out my problem: `$user->getProfile()->getAdmin()->getUser()->hasPermission('Can.Delete');`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sfGuardPlugin or sfDoctrineGuardPlugin you can get all user permissions by calling `getAllPermissions()` inside actions with:

```
$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getAllPermissions();
```

or inside models with:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getAllPermissions();
```

either way you have to call `getGuardUser`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the sfGuardPlugin, you have the `sf_guard_user`, `sf_guard_permission` and `sf_guard_group` tables in your databse. So you can query that tables to obtain the permission of an specific user doing something like:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add('username',$specificName);

$userPeer = new sfGuardUserPeer();
$user = $userPeer->doSelect($c);

$credentials = $user->getPermissions();
```

that way in `$credentials` you'll have an array of all the permissions (permissions are the credentials in sfGuardPlugin) of the selected user.

Good luck